# navigationController?.setViewControllers works delayed in method viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift5

`navigationController?.setViewControllers` works delayed in `override func viewDidAppear(` , in other cirsumstances, it works fine.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print(self.navigationController?.children)
    print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)
    var array = self.navigationController?.children
    array!.insert(ViewController(), at: array!.count - 1)
    navigationController?.setViewControllers(array!, animated: false)
    print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)
}
```

It prints:

```
Optional([<One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b4021e0>, <One.TwoViewController: 0x7f9a1b40e320>])
Optional([<One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b4021e0>, <One.TwoViewController: 0x7f9a1b40e320>])
Optional([<One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b4021e0>, <One.TwoViewController: 0x7f9a1b40e320>])
```

in other cirsumstances, it works fine. like a button click.

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    print(self.navigationController?.children)
    print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)
    var array = self.navigationController?.children
    array!.insert(ViewController(), at: array!.count - 1)
    navigationController?.setViewControllers(array!, animated: false)
    print(self.navigationController?.viewControllers)
}


Optional([<One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b4021e0>, <One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b520dc0>, <One.TwoViewController: 0x7f9a1b40e320>])
Optional([<One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b4021e0>, <One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b520dc0>, <One.TwoViewController: 0x7f9a1b40e320>])
Optional([<One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b4021e0>, <One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b520dc0>, <One.ViewController: 0x7f9a1b40cd10>, <One.TwoViewController: 0x7f9a1b40e320>])
```

It works as expected.

The two methods worked one after an other.

I think `navigationController?.setViewControllers` works  in `override func viewDidAppear(`,  a little delayed.

What is the machanism?

Comment: what happens if you set animated value to false at `super.viewDidAppear(false)`

Comment: @mbutan , as usual, nothing special. I don't know what to notice